# Bootstrap 4 responsive input with search button unaligned with small media

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have created an input text beside a button like so:

[image: preview here]

It looks good on the regular computer screen, this is exactly how it supposed to look like. but in a phone device view, it's unaligned:

[image: unaligned preview here]

This is the working code I got:

```
<!-- Add Filer Form -->
<div class="row py-4 bg-darkblue">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group row offset-md-1">
                <label for="filerAddress" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-white font-weight-bold">Filer ID</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filerAddress" placeholder="">
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="btn px-5 btn-light">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row offset-md-1">
                <label for="filerName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-white font-weight-bold">Filer Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="">
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="btn px-5 btn-light">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row offset-md-1">
                <label for="filerType" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-white font-weight-bold">Filer Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="">
                </div>      

                <button type="button" class="btn px-5 btn-light">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>                           
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- #END# Add Filer Form -->
```

How can I fix this? And what things should I know in order to prevent this when I create more in the future?

Comment: do you want in phone the button stay or down line?

Comment: I would like to see which one is better. My original thoughts would be for the button to stay beside the input field, but then the input field would be shorter and I think that's not pretty. Maybe down line is better, but I would like to check first for comparison =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will resolve your issue

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Add Filer Form -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-4 bg-darkblue">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group offset-md-1">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="filerAddress" class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Filer ID</label>
            <div class="col-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filerAddress" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search
       </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group offset-md-1">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="filerAddress" class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Filer ID</label>
            <div class="col-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filerAddress" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search
       </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group offset-md-1">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="filerAddress" class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Filer ID</label>
            <div class="col-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filerAddress" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search
       </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This did the trick. I just did some minimal changes in my code. Thank you very much! Can you give me some good bootstrap grid tutorials besides the docs? Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Use `col-6` instead of `col-sm-6` 
Use `offset-1` instead of `offset-md-1`
Use `col-3` instead of `col-sm-2`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Add Filer Form -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row py-4 bg-secondary">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group row offset-1">
            <label for="filerAddress" class="col-3 col-form-label text-white font-weight-bold">Filer ID</label>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filerAddress" placeholder="">
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn px-5 btn-light">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row offset-1">
            <label for="filerName" class="col-3 col-form-label text-white font-weight-bold">Filer Name</label>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="">
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn px-5 btn-light">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row offset-1">
            <label for="filerType" class="col-3 col-form-label text-white font-weight-bold">Filer Type</label>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="">
            </div>      

            <button type="button" class="btn px-5 btn-light">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>                           
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try this one. Please wait.. thank you very much!

Comment: I tried your suggestion.. but it looked like [this..](https://imgur.com/a/kU0SyBn) It's not properly aligned..

Comment: Have you added container div around your row like i did in the sample above?

Comment: Oh I forgot, but I added it just now, and it looks like [this..](https://imgur.com/a/NXCReL5) =) it looks well on normal laptop screen =) but it's not dark blue color now all the way to the edge.. maybe because of the new container..

Comment: Use container-fluid instead of container

Comment: I dont know why its not working for you. On which div you are applying the background color(dark blue). May be something else on your page is causing the issue, If you can show me the entire page html , may be i can figure out the issue

Comment: Sorry late response.. I just went out and I just got back, and I just tried the other response out of curiosity.. It seemed to work.. Thank you very much for your help!!